# Download for the Heros example app in the Angular Style Guide

Tags: angular, coding-style, design-guidelines

On the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide), all of the examples are using a Hero application. I would love to download a working version of the application because I'd like to page through it in completeness, as I generally learn fast by viewing working code.

I've looked on the page for a download link, and I can't find one. The [Tour of Heros Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) looks to be different, and so does this [one on Github](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes).

Can someone please direct me to a downloadable working version of this app?

Comment: Yes I do have git installed.

Comment: Refer to this example: https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular6-example-app